# Hibernate OneToOne biderectional relation between two embedded Id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.1

I'm triying to make a biderectional relation between two classes with Embeddable Id .

The relation take the same columns from the two embedded Id's

Basically the structures are as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON)
public class Person implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonId entityb;


    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumns({
                @JoinColumn(name = "code", referencedColumnName = "code", updatable = false),
                @JoinColumn(name = "num", referencedColumnName = "num", updatable = false) })
        private Home home;

   // Setters Getters.....
}



 @Embeddable
public class PersonId implements Serializable{


    @Column(name = "code")
    private Integer code;

    @Column(name = "num")
    private Integer num;

    // Setters Getters.....

}




   @Entity
@Table(name="HOME)
public class Home implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    private HomeId entityb;


    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "adresse")
    private String adresse;

   // Setters Getters.....
}



@Embeddable
public class HomeId implements Serializable{


    @Column(name = "code")
    private Integer code;

    @Column(name = "num")
    private Integer num;

    // Setters Getters.....

}
```

I fail to see the mistake on mapping entities, since both ids are manually assigned?.

I get a "ReseltSet" error whene a i call a DAO to get all rows from Person entity with @Query(value="select p from Person p")

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2168)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1931)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:938)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1490)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1463)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:214)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 94 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You should put entire exception stack & the code snippet that deals with ResultSet.

Comment: can you provide exception

Comment: Please provide the code which throws ecxception

Comment: i updated with exception